# How to use smtp mail server?

Tags: java, android, email, smtp

I'm using latest version of Android studio and want to send mail programmatically in java.
I'm using dependencies as shown in screenshot.
But mail not sending.

Suggest me the best solution for gmail smtp service.

I don't want to use any other file like mail.jar and etc
I saw many tutorials but there are no error in codes but mail not sent.

Take a look of my code

**Dependencies**

```
dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.5.1'
    implementation 'com.sun.mail:android-mail:1.6.2'
    implementation 'com.sun.mail:android-activation:1.6.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.6.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;

import javax.mail.Authenticator;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;

import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.Properties;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    String msg = "hello";
    String subject = "test";
    String to = "receiver mail";
    String from = "sender mail";
    String host = "smtp.gmail.com";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button btn = findViewById(R.id.send);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Properties p = System.getProperties();
                p.setProperty("mail.smtp.host",host);
                p.setProperty("mail.smtp.port","465");
                p.setProperty("mail.smtp.ssl.enable", "true");
                p.setProperty("mail.smtp.auth","true");

                Session session =  Session.getInstance(p, new Authenticator() {
                    @Override
                    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                        return new PasswordAuthentication(from,"password");
                    }
                });

                session.setDebug(true);
                MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
                try {
                    message.setFrom(from);
                    message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,new InternetAddress(to));
                    message.setSubject(subject);
                    message.setText(msg);
                    Transport.send(message);
                    System.out.println("Sent success.....");
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.DDPL"
        tools:targetApi="31">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.lib_name"
                android:value="" />
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Send the email securely from your server. As it stands, anyone can get your email credentials from your app and use them to send spam (or worse) from your email account. Or, use `ACTION_SEND`/`ACTION_SENDTO` and let the user send the email from their preferred app.

Comment: But I don't want to redirect at any other app ?

Comment: Then send the email securely from your server.

Comment: How to send ? Please suggest me

Comment: `Transport transport = session.getTransport("smtp");` , `        transport.connect("yourmailuser@yourmail.domain","yourmaipassword");`,